# How to install GDAL 2.4.4 with GEOS support in Python 3.7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, gdal, geos

I seem unable to get GEOS support for GDAL 2.4.4 to work in Python on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

I've done the following:

1. Installed `libgeos-dev` on my system
2. Downloaded and extracted gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz
3. `./configure --with-proj --with-python=$(which python) --with-geos=yes`
4. `make && sudo make install` (The output indicated `GEOS support: yes` after installation)
5. In the `swig/python` directory, did a `pip install .`
6. Put the site-packages for osgeo and gdal install location on both my `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`

When I go into my python shell, I try to use Centroid, but get an error.

```
from osgeo import ogr
point = """{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-90.02001032734194,35.127405562848075]}"""
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(point)
geom.Centroid()
ERROR 6: GEOS support not enabled.
```

I can import `gdal` and `ogr` fine, they are located where I expect with the versions I expect, but for some reason it does not have GEOS support.

`gdalinfo --version` is indeed `2.4.4` and the install is where I expect.

Tried installing `pygdal==2.4.4.6`, but it did not help.

System info:

```
GDAL version: 2.4.4
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Python: 3.7.10
```

What have I done wrong or what more can I check?

Comment: Why to try to install an unmaintained GDAL 2.4 version while the current version is 3.2?

Comment: Installing the current version available in Ubuntu 20.04 works fine, only from apt. I still can't get it to work trying to install from source. I am trying to work with an older codebase that restricts version to <3.0.0.